# How can you prevent XSS that is sent as part of URL field

Tags: javascript, java, security, xss

Currently I am displaying a link on a specific webpage with the URL set by a user through a POST request. The website is shown to a second user (user 2) which displays that link. When the link is clicked, it will go back to user 1's webpage (or that's what it is intended to be). But this came up recently where if the URL is modified or if the user 1 is a bad user, it sets the URL as `Javascript://%0Aalert(document.domain)//`, when the link is clicked it will execute the script.

How can this URL be validated in Java and prevent the user 1 from setting this as the URI instead right when the POST request comes in?

Comment: Java is not javascript

Comment: Yup i know that. My backend server is in java. The POST request comes to the server and I want to validate the URL.

Comment: Then you need to explain more how you have things set up, it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to solve this problem, which you can use together or separately:

1. Parse the received URL and check that all of its component parts (scheme, hostname, port, path, query string, etc.) contain reasonable values that your app would normally generate and that you trust to be harmless.

   In particular, just checking that the scheme is `http` and/or `https` would be sufficient to stop the specific attack mentioned in your question, although you almost certainly should do a bit more validation than just that.
2. When originally generating the URL, calculate a cryptographic [message authentication code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) of it (using a secret key stored on your server and never sent to the client) and send it alongside the URL.  When you receive the URL back from the client, verify that the MAC still matches.

   This is a general technique for making sure that values that *should* be relayed unchanged by the client back to the server aren't tampered with.  If you have several such values, instead of just a single URL, you can encode them all into a single string and calculate a single MAC on all of them.  Just make sure that the encoding is deterministic, so that you can repeat it exactly when verifying the MAC.  Also, you may want to combine additional metadata such as the user's ID and/or a timestamp into the MAC input in order to protect against [replay attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack).

Comment: Thanks! I don't want to restrict is based on http or https since I want to allow other valid URIs too (maybe like google://) and for the second solution since the user 1 does a POST request to set the URL, I'm a little confused how the secret key might be useful in that case when that data is sent to user 2 who is the client. Let me know what you think!

Comment: If the URL comes from an untrusted source (and other users generally do count as untrusted sources) and you don't want to restrict it in any way, then the problem is fundamentally unsolvable. After all, `javascript:` is a perfectly valid URI scheme that a user might legitimately want to choose. The closest you can get is to compile a list of "safe" URI schemes — which should _not_ include `javascript:` — and disallow anything else.

Comment: That makes sense. Yup in my case I am considering user 1 to be an untrusted source so I might have to go with a list of safe URIs. Thanks again!